# On MacOS, hunspell can't find existing .aff and .dic files in Library/Spelling/

Tags: macos, emacs, hunspell, spelling

I have downloaded hunspell with a brew command, and want to use it in Emacs, but hunspell doesn't seem to locate my `*.aff` and `*.dic` files in `~/Library/Spelling`, even though they are there.

With the command line command `hunspell -D`, the result is:

```
SEARCH PATH:
.::/usr/share/hunspell:/usr/share/myspell:/usr/share/myspell/dicts:/Library/Spelling:/Users/macbook/.openoffice.org/3/user/wordbook:/Users/macbook/.openoffice.org2/user/wordbook:/Users/macbook/.openoffice.org2.0/user/wordbook:/Users/macbook/Library/Spelling:/opt/openoffice.org/basis3.0/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org/basis3.0/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.4/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.4/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.3/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.3/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.2/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.2/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.1/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.1/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.0/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.0/share/dict/ooo
AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES (path is not mandatory for -d option):
/Users/macbook/Library/Spelling/cs_CZ
```

Here, **cs_CZ** is the name of a file where my personal spelling is stored. There are other files in the folder, including `cs_CZ.aff` and `cs_CZ.dic`, as well as `en_GB`, but hunspell simply ignores those.

In Emacs, I tried:

```lisp
(setenv "DICPATH"
    (concat (getenv "HOME") "/Library/Spelling"))
(when (executable-find "hunspell")
      (setq-default ispell-program-name "hunspell")
      (setq ispell-really-hunspell t))
```

After running ispell-change-dictinary with a recommended input "czech", ispell-word gives me:

> Starting new Ispell process hunspell with czech dictionary...
>   ispell-init-process: Can't open affix or dictionary files for
>   dictionary named "czech".

...and flyspell-mode:

> Error enabling Flyspell mode: (Can't open affix or dictionary files
>   for dictionary named "czech".)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Spell-checkers in Emacs look up spelling in two dictionaries: the standard dictionary and your personal dictionary. The standard dictionary is specified by the variable `ispell-local-dictionary` or, if that is `nil`, by the variable `ispell-dictionary`. And as I can see in your output, Hunspell have  only `cs_CZ`, but not `czech` dictionary:

```
AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES (path is not mandatory for -d option):
/Users/macbook/Library/Spelling/cs_CZ
```

By the way, Hunspell 1.7.0 was broken. For more see: https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/issues/608. You can compare the output between

```
hunspell -D
```

and

```
hunspell -D /dev/null
```

to see the difference.

First, set the desired dictionary name you have installed:

```lisp
;; Default dictionary to use
(setq ispell-local-dictionary "czech")
```

To see a list of found and parsed dictionaries use <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `ispell-hunspell-dict-paths-alist`.

In addition, I would like to suggest add your preferred dictionaries to `ispell-local-dictionary-alist`. This variable used to specify an *alist* of dictionaries and their associated parameters. Note, you have to use the same dictionary name a in `ispell-dictionary`. Something like this should work:

```lisp
;; Here ("-d" "cs_CZ") is dictionary file name.
;; You could use '("-d" "file1,file2")' form to use multiple dictionaries.
(add-to-list
 'ispell-local-dictionary-alist
 '(("czech" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha]]" "[0-9']" t
    ("-d" "cs_CZ") nil utf-8)))
```

Note, Homebrew itself provides no dictionaries for Hunspell, but you can download
compatible dictionaries from other sources, such as https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/czech-dictionaries. For instructions see for example: https://passingcuriosity.com/2017/emacs-hunspell-and-dictionaries.

Finally, I highly recommend to set `DICTIONARY` environment variable on macOS.  Without this variable you'll see on macOS something like this:

> Can't open affix or dictionary files for dictionary named "XXX"

I managed to reproduce this issue on macOS. But on Linux, with the same configuration and Emacs version everything works fine. To set dictionary file name use `setenv` defun as follows:

```lisp
(when (string-equal system-type "darwin") ; Only for macOs
  ;; Dictionary file name
  (setenv "DICTIONARY" "cs_CZ"))
```

This environment variable is used by Hunspell. For more see `man 1 hunspell`.